# What are the key differences between the Shazam and Soundhound Apps?

Tags: iphone, ipad, applications, shazam

Both seem to do roughly the same thing.   What, if anything, are the relevant differences?

Answer (score 6):

Don't know if there are really major differences that set one far apart from the other.

One of the bigger differentiators is that Soundhound claims to recoginze songs that are hummed and/or sung by the user.

From a purely opinion oriented view, I've had better success with Soundhound at identifying songs than Shazam - but both do the job pretty well. Soundhound also seems to be quicker at returning results for me than Shazam. Again, that's just my own experience and I've, by no means, done exhaustive testing between the two.

Shazam seems to have better search but Soundhound can search by lyrics.

Comment: And soundhound has been around for quite longer I believe. It used to be called **midomi**.

Comment: FWIW - I have used Shazam and Soundhound and found that SoundHound finds songs that Shazam doesn't but I've never had Shazam find a song Soundhound couldn't.

Comment: +1 for SoundHound finding more songs than Shazam. I've had SH find songs despite obscene amounts of ambient noise (crowds cheering, people talking loudly, etc.). I bought both years ago and bounced between the two, favoring one over the other, but over time, just found SH to be far more reliable.

Answer (score -1):

[Here's a great video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGlsnEnKFoI&feature=channel_video_title) about SoundHound vs. Shazam that should help answer your question:

Comment: Can you summarize for those who don't have time to watch a video?